# How to reproducibly include R code in Word documents with Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, ms-word, r-markdown, knitr, pretty-print

I have some R code in a package. I don't want to copy that code, but I want to display it in a pretty way in Word with syntax highlighting without any manual steps.

I looked at `styler::style_text` in combination of `capture.output` and that looks nice in the browser, but all the formatting is lost when knitting to Word. Is there some way to preserve it? I'm thinking the best thing would be to have Word native styling but the next best (acceptable) thing would be to somehow render the output to an image and include that. Has anyone done these things to document their code in a report?

```r
show_code = function (fun) {
  stopifnot(is.function(fun))
  out = capture.output(fun)
  n = length(out)
  without_bytecode_and_env_lines = -1*c(n-1, n)
  code = paste(out[without_bytecode_and_env_lines], collapse = "\n")
  styler::style_text(code)
}
```

Comment: just run the plain code and knit to work. for example have a chunck as `\`\`\`{r} lm\`\`\``  and knit to word

Comment: I'm not interested in "knitting the work". I have a targets workflow which does all that elsewhere.  I'm interested in documenting how the functions used by that workflow work.

Comment: I meant to knit to word. Not work

Comment: That produces code which is hard to read because it does not have syntax highlighting and isn't wrapped right and has `##` prefixed on each line.

Comment: You can remove the `##` by including the chunk option comment = "". But I see what you mean, there is no highlighting done. Do you need to highlight specific lines?

Comment: I don't think so. I just want to highlight the whole thing. With `show_code` it looks good in the browser and the code layout looks reasonable in Word. I would want the font to be bigger for sure, though.

Comment: I thought maybe there would be a solution with webshot2.

Comment: I also hoped that maybe there might be a way to get code highlighting with `officedown`.

Comment: I am unable to get the `show_code` function to work

Comment: I might have made a typo in transcribing it, since I was uncomfortable with logging in to SO on the computer I wrote the code on.

Comment: I missed the minus sign to drop the function metadata lines R prints. I fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are trying to use syntax highlighting on the output of `show_code` and to do that, you simply need to use the options `comment=""` and `class.output="r"` and syntax highlighting will apply to the output.

---

````
---
title: "Source Code highlighting"
output: 
  word_document:
    highlight: kate
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

```{r echo=FALSE}
show_code = function (fun) {
  stopifnot(is.function(fun))
  out = capture.output(fun)
  n = length(out)
  without_bytecode_and_env_lines = c(n-1, n)
  code = paste0(out[-without_bytecode_and_env_lines], collapse = "\n")
  styler::style_text(code)
}
```

### The source code for `lm`

```{r comment='', echo=FALSE, class.output = "r"}
show_code(lm)
```
````

---

[image: syntax highlighting in Output]

---